# Jss-rtl plugin doesn't work after upgrading material ui from v4 to v5

Tags: material-ui, next.js, jss

I Upgraded material ui v4 to v5 since then jss-rtl doesn't work properly.The project is written in next js.
_app.js :

```
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });
const emotionCache = {
    LTR: createCache({
        key: 'ltr',
        prepend: true,
    }),
    RTL: createCache({
        key: 'css',
        stylisPlugins: [rtlPlugin],
        prepend: true,
    }),
};
const cache = createCache({ key: 'css' });
cache.compat = true;
const selectedCache = direction !== 'rtl' ? emotionCache.LTR : emotionCache.RTL;
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
            {/* <CacheProvider value={selectedCache}> */}
            <ThemeProvider theme={themes}>
                    <CssBaseline />
                        ...
            </ThemeProvider>
            {/* </CacheProvider> */}
        </StylesProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
```

CacheProvider is emotion/react component.I thought it has a conflict with jss so I commented that but it doesn't change. when CacheProvider is enabled in RTL mode it works properly with material components. but the other elements that I wrote in jss don't flip in rtl. I checked in material v4 these elements had classes like these: .jss45, but in v5 it doesn't have these classes instead their classes are something like this: .makeStyles-listContainer-201 that doesn't change in RTL mode.

Comment: Have you got any solution on this? @pouryak ?

Comment: @Urvi_204 No,I have not